# Most played games from steam API

Tags: json, api, steam, steam-web-api

Is there a possibility to get JSON file with the most played games from the steam API? Can't find the right method from the steam documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valve doesn't provide a most-played endpoint - you'd need to collect play stats for every game yourself. [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/) and [SteamSpy](http://steamspy.com/) both aggregate those stats, and the latter has [an API](http://steamspy.com/api.php) you can query for some Top 100 lists.